# Does Stack Overflow reset reputation on rule violation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, account-suspension

How could this person earn that many badges with 1 reputation point?

[image]

Comment: if they are suspended, yes, while they are suspended, they are dropped at 1

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder who that is...

Comment: It's Col. Shrapnel  :)

Comment: @Christian, Nope. He's now called "[Your common sense](https://archive.is/HfWTH)". And do you reckon that's his real face?

Comment: @Pacerier But that's the alias he uses on GitHub ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are suspended your reputation is set to 1 for the duration of the suspension.

It is restored to it's correct value after the suspension is over.

Comment: ... which might be bigger or smaller than at the time of suspension.